# building NuSMV 2.6 from source, make utility on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nusmv

I am trying to build NuSMV on Ubuntu 17.04,using cmake utility.

Used cmake tool to create make file, but when I try to use make utility it gives the error

```
 Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:824: recipe for target 'build-cudd/util/CMakeFiles/CUDD_UTIL_LIB.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [build-cudd/util/CMakeFiles/CUDD_UTIL_LIB.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can anyone please help. How to solve it

Answer (score 1):

If the detail information of the problem is like

```
NuSMV-2.6.0/cudd-2.4.1.1/util/pipefork.c:46:16: error: storage size of ‘status’ isn’t known union wait status;
```

you can open the pipefork.c and try to alter the line 43 to

```
#if (defined __linux__) || (defined __hpux) || (defined __osf__) || (defined _IBMR2) || (defined __SVR4) || (defined __CYGWIN32__) || (defined __MINGW32__)
```